# Looping slideshow and changing animation javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Forgive, very very very new to Javascript. Adding in a slideshow for a project at uni, Really basic function to run to get these images to work in a slideshow,

But after it completes it exits and doesn't repeat or loop like I would like it too, 
Also if i wanted to have a fade animation so its not just one image straight into next what would be the best way?

Thanks.

```
<-- HTML -->
<img id="Slide" src="images/okc4.jpg" width=640 height=400 />

//javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
                    var slideimages = new Array() 
                        slideimages[0] = new Image()
                        slideimages[0].src = "image.jpg" 
                        slideimages[1] = new Image()
                        slideimages[1].src = "image.jpg"
                        slideimages[2] = new Image()
                        slideimages[2].src = "image.jpg"
                    var step = 0;

                    function slideit(){

                     document.getElementById("Slide").src = slideimages[step].src
                     if (step<=2) {
                      step++
                     }else{
                      step=0
                    }

                     setInterval("slideit()",2500)
                    }

                    slideit()
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
                    var slideimages = new Array() 
                        slideimages[0] = new Image()
                        slideimages[0].src = "image.jpg" 
                        slideimages[1] = new Image()
                        slideimages[1].src = "image.jpg"
                        slideimages[2] = new Image()
                        slideimages[2].src = "image.jpg"
                    var step = 0;

                    function slideit(){

                     document.getElementById("Slide").src = slideimages[step].src
                     if (step<2) {
                      step++
                     }else{
                      step=0
                    }

                    }

                    setInterval(function(){slideit();},2500)
```

setInterval is enough to make the function execute every 2.5 seconds.

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/rafaelropota/7qr7qnsx/1/

Comment: can you please try again? (the step must be strictly less than 2 if you have 3 images - with step <= 2, in the case of step=2, you will go through step++ (step will become 3) and slideimages[3] does not exist. Also, i wrapped slideit() into function(){}.

Comment: I apologise, small typo and it is working. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8mdLz8tw/1/

Your index does not exist anymore, will grow to 3 and it will trow an error, also I have a made your code a bit different with an anonymous function. In the console you can see the switch and restart, since all the pictures are the same if you use lorempixel :)

```
var slideimages = new Array()
slideimages[0] = new Image()
slideimages[0].src = "http://lorempixel.com/640/400/"//replaced pics for fiddle
slideimages[1] = new Image()
slideimages[1].src = "http://lorempixel.com/640/400/"
slideimages[2] = new Image()
slideimages[2].src = "http://lorempixel.com/640/400/"
var step = 0;

setInterval(function () {

    document.getElementById("Slide").src = slideimages[step].src;
    if (step < 2) {//Here was your mistake, if you increase when it is exactly 2 your step will go to three and thus throw an error since you don't have an image indexed with three
        step++;
        console.log(step);
        console.log("switched");
    } else {
        step = 0;
        console.log("restart");
    }


}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thank you Mikey, such a simple error that had me confused for awhile.

Answer (score 1):

To make it loop, like you wished, you have to set it to 0 when step reaches a size 1 smaller then the length of the array.

```
             var slideimages = new Array() 
                    slideimages[0] = new Image()
                    slideimages[0].src = "image.jpg" 
                    slideimages[1] = new Image()
                    slideimages[1].src = "image2.jpg"
                    slideimages[2] = new Image()
                    slideimages[2].src = "image3.jpg"
                var step = 0;

                function slideit(){

                 document.getElementById("Slide").src = slideimages[step].src
                 if (step < slideimages.length-1) {
                  step++
                 }else{
                  step=0
                }

                }

                setInterval(slideit,2500)
```

See fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bneb2bpw/2/

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answers have covered the loop - but about what you said about a fading transition...

I'd use jQuery to create this effect. 
Take a look at jQuery's [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) , that's the most commonly used method.

However, sometimes I like to make my own transition by using two other jQuery methods - `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`.

```
window.onload = function () {
    setInterval(function () {

        $("#Slide").fadeOut(2000, function () {

            $("#Slide").attr("src", slideimages[i].toString());
            $("#Slide").fadeIn();
        });
        i++;

        if (i >= 2) i = 0;

    }, 2500);
};
```

This fades out the image element, and once it has faded out, changes it's source like you were doing before. 
After the source has changed, it fades back in - giving a 'fade transition' effect!  Working example - [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fxt2oL7n/9/)

Comment: Thanks Piggy, I havn't touched on any jQuery yet but will look this up thanks for getting back with an animation response

Comment: I realised after I posted that you hadn't mentioned jQuery, woops! Its well worth a look at once you're comfortable though :) no problem!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need to create new Image object to change src elements. Also setInterval() is not used as it intended.

```
<img id="Slide" src="images/okc4.jpg" width=640 height=400 />

//javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
                    var slideimages = ["image.jpg","image.jpg","image.jpg"];                            
                    var step = 0;

                    function slideit(){
                       document.getElementById("Slide").src = slideimages[step]
                       if (step<slideimages.length) {
                        step++
                       }else{
                        step=0
                       }

                     setInterval(slideit,2500)
                    }

                    slideit()
</script>
```